# How to receive information from a contact form by email with laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, email

Hello I have created a contact form with the following fields (name, contact, email, subject, message) I can retrieve the information in my database. I want to redo the same form by retrieving the information in my mailbox but I don't know how to do the configuration see by where I started.
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Please elaborate on retrieving info from mailbox.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your not new to Laravel, when you receive the fields, follow the steps in the Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#writing-mailables) to send the data to any mail of your choosing.